# Turn off fee destruction in PPCoin

Tags: peercoin, altcoin

In the sourcecode of [PPCoin/SRC/MAIN.CPP](https://github.com/gooios/ppcoin/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L1433) line 1433 I read: fees are destroyed to compensate the entire network.

I want to turn it off that fees are destroyed, if I change this code will it work?

```
// ppcoin: fees are not collected by miners as in bitcoin
// ppcoin: fees are destroyed to compensate the entire network
if (fDebug && GetBoolArg("-printcreation"))
    printf("ConnectBlock() : destroy=%s nFees=%"PRI64d"\n", FormatMoney(nFees).c_str(), nFees);
```

If I change `destroy=%s` to `destroy=%$$$`, will it stop destroying fees?

Comment: I'll take a look through the code, but i don't think that is the only place it is referenced in that code

Answer (score 1):

No. That's a `printf` statement, so you will only prevent the printing, not the actual destruction.